# SQLSTATE [42000] when adding data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

When parsing an xml file and adding it to the database, it displays an error during the script operation:

```
$sql->exec("INSERT INTO 'example' VALUES('$id', '$title', '$link')");
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''example'
>   VALUES('phpmysqljquery-przeciagnij-z-wy'
>   at line 1

Can anyone say what is wrong?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong quoting style. Database, table and column identifiers use a different approach:

```
INSERT INTO `example` VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Double and single quotes are *only* for strings. You can't insert stuff into a string.

Comment: That's technically a different question, but the trick there is to use `prepare` first, then `execute` second. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for more examples.

Comment: I rolled the question back.